# Apache Beam not writing data to BigQuery using 2 millions lines file as side input

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm joining data from two data sources with `Apache Beam Python SDK 2.48.0`:

- one is bounded, using `beam.io.ReadFromText`. It is a json.gz file
- one is unbounded, using `beam.io.ReadFromPubSub` + a Window `beam.WindowInto(beam.window.Sessions(3600), trigger=beam.trigger.Repeatedly(beam.trigger.AfterCount(1)), accumulation_mode=beam.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)` (also works with a `GlobalWindows`)

From both sides, the data is preprocessed, joined, processed again, then written to BigQuery using `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery`.

The bounded data is injected as a `Side Input` into a `ParDo` function that is used for the join operation:

```
enriched_unbounded_pcol = (
    unbounded_pcol
    | beam.ParDo(PreprocessUnbounded()) # return tuples
    | beam.ParDo(LeftJoiner(), side_input_file=beam.pvalue.AsDict(side_input_file)))
```

LeftJoiner `ParDo` class:

```
class LeftJoiner(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, file, **kwargs):
        v1, v2 = file
        side_input_file= kwargs["side_input_file"]
        v3 = side_input_file.get(v1)

        yield compute_stuff(v3) # not compute-heavy
```

With a small sample of about 35KB, the file is read accordingly and the join is written on the `BigQuery` table.

However, the real file is around 35MB and has ~2 millions lines. When using this file, the joined data is never written to `BigQuery`.
Note that the real file is loaded correctly under a few minutes.

Using logs, the LeftJoiner `ParDo` operation does not seem to be performed.

I suppose `Dataflow` should be handling much larger files than that. Am I missing anything?
Should I change the worker cache size or enable extra features like [Dataflow Prime](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/enable-dataflow-prime)?

Note that I also tried to invert the process: I injected the unbounded data as a `Side Input` and it works with the small 35KB sample file. Whenever the real file is used, the function in which it's injected is blocked or waiting indefinitely.

Comment: How long did you run the pipeline? How do you inject the side input into the ParDo? Can you share a code sample?

Comment: Original post updated. Pipeline was run for 30mn, maybe more. Note that the 35MB file is loaded correctly in a few minutes, which is not a problem.

Comment: How does `compute_stuff` handle `v3=None`? It could be that, due to the windowing, the side input is empty (not loaded yet or something like that) and thus nothing is written to BQ? See [programming guide](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs-windowing)

Comment: `v3=None` is a use-case handled. I tried to replace the `ParDo` with a `Filter` with the `Side Input` and same result: the size of the file blocks/puts on wait the function and doesn't produce any output.

Comment: Hi @Grégoire Borel, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.